# Skirting boards over vinyl - seal with silicone?

Tags: vinyl-flooring, skirting

Thinking of sealing under the skirting boards, as the flooring is waterproof.

I have laid 22 square metres of vinyl planks in an apartment; the sort that lock together as in the photo. Now I am ready to glue and nail skirting boards onto the wall made of plasterboard (drywall).

I understand about leaving a gap at the edges of the flooring for expansion - I have done this.

But when I spill my tea on the floor it may run under the skirting board and get under the vinyl flooring. I would like to prevent this.

Would a line of silicone under the skirting boards stop this? I hope the summer expansion of the floor would not be hindered by this.[image]

Comment: I've only ever seen the skirt boards sealed to the floor in areas that are expected to get _wet_ (not just damp). i.e. in bathrooms where you would also have a waterproofed floor, as well. I don't think you'd want to do that in a kitchen, living room, or bedroom.

Comment: We have a different reason for wanting to do it (but haven't tried yet). The guy who put the flooring down didn't seal the underlay against the wall so we have draughts coming up under the skirting boards from the crawlspace. Sealing them seems easier than ripping out half the skirting boards in our house.

Comment: I have sealed under the skirting boards with silicone sealant. Remind me in March '23 (after summer) to report if the silicon has broken, or the boards warped